# Image not being updated in JPanel while image path is changed

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel

I've built a custom class extending the JPanel to draw in it.
So far so good, when I create an object of it it renders just fine.
The problem comes when I change the path, the image won't update! I've tried the repaint() & revalidate() methods, but still it won't update.. 
Here is the source of the class:

```
public class Screen extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage image;
    private String path2;

    public Screen(String path1) {
        path2=path1;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path2));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth() * 2, image.getHeight() * 2, null);
    }

    public void setPath2(String path) {
        this.path2 = path;
    }

    public String getPath2() {
        return path2;
    }
}
```

I'm working with GUI Builder of Netbeans, so I've also create a method to be called when the user changes the ComboBox value. The path1&path2 variables change value, but the image wont update..
ComboBox method:

```
private void TILE_ITEMS_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    

    String path="/res/"+TILE_ITEMS.getSelectedItem().toString()+".png";
    PREVIEW_PANEL.setPath2(path);
    PREVIEW_PANEL.revalidate();
    PREVIEW_PANEL.repaint();        
}
```

TO BE NOTICED:: The object is created **OUTSIDE** of the TILE_ITEMS_ActionPerformed method, at the TOP of the source of my GUI class..
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: When the given answers helped to solve your question, then you should accept one of them. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

you should read the image for the new path and put it in the image variable then repaint the component so you should copy the code from the Screen constructer then put it in set path methode because if you didnt do that the path will changes but the bufferedImage will not change

Answer (score 1):

The displayed image in your `Screen` class didn't update
because in your `setPath2` method you missed to reload your `image`
(like you did correctly in the constructor).

The fixed `setPath2` method would like this:

```
public void setPath2(String path) {
    this.path2 = path;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path2));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

Having fixed this you could simplify your constructor like this:

```
public Screen(String path1) {
    setPath2(path1);
}
```

Furthermore, then you can simplify your `ActionPerformed` method by removing `revalidate` and `repaint` there:

```
private void TILE_ITEMS_ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {    

    String path="/res/"+TILE_ITEMS.getSelectedItem().toString()+".png";
    PREVIEW_PANEL.setPath2(path);
}
```